# How to get the count of failed in paper for a particular Student from a Student Collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection

```
{
"name" : "arjun",
"Roll NO" : 123,
"timestamp" : {
    "full" : "Wed Mar 23 10:38:12 UTC 2016"
}
"failed_in" : "Mathematics",
```

}

```
{
"name" : "Ram",
"Roll NO" : 103,
"timestamp" : {
    "full" : "Wed Mar 23 10:38:12 UTC 2016"
}
"failed_in" : "English",
```

}

```
{
"name" : "Ram",
"Roll NO" : 103,
"timestamp" : {
    "full" : "Wed Mar 23 10:38:12 UTC 2016"
}
"failed_in" : "Science",
```

}

```
{
"name" : "arjun",
"Roll NO" : 123,
"timestamp" : {
    "full" : "Thur April 18 10:38:12 UTC 2016"
}
"failed_in" : "English",
```

}

```
{
"name" : "arjun",
"Roll NO" : 123,
"timestamp" : {
    "full" : "Wed Mar 23 10:38:12 UTC 2016"
}
"failed_in" : "Mathematics",
```

}

I want a output like below sort By date.

```
{
'name':'arjun',
failed_in:[{'mathematics':2},{'english':1}]
```

}

```
{
'name':'ram',
failed_in:[{'science':1},{'english':1}]
```

}
Could you please give the Query for it ?? I hav etried this in some horrible ways , but non of them works.

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link to update your question and show code of what you have attempted, regardless of them being horrible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do that.I have tested it and works perfect.

db.getCollection('tests').aggregate([{$match:{"Roll NO":103}},
{ $group : {
            _id : "$Roll NO",
            failed_in: { $push : "$failed_in" }
        }},
])